# Is there an easy way to create square buffers around point and if they intersect, merge them?

Tags: python, buffer, coordinates, geospatial

I am trying to create square buffers around given points, I am able to create circular buffers but not square ones.

```
from shapely.ops import transform
from shapely.geometry import Point
    local_azimuthal_projection = "+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(lat, lon)
                    wgs84_to_aeqd = partial(
                        pyproj.transform,
                        pyproj.Proj('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'),
                        pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
                    )
                    aeqd_to_wgs84 = partial(
                        pyproj.transform,
                        pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
                        pyproj.Proj('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'),
                    )

                    point_transformed = transform(wgs84_to_aeqd, Point(float(lon), float(lat)))
                    buffer = point_transformed.buffer(0.5*1000)
                    buffered_geom = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84, buffer).exterior.coords[:]
```

Also, if I have some buffers that overlap, how can I merge them?

Answer (score 0):

In jaguardb, it should be simply
Select union(buffer(p1), buffer(p2)) from t where intersect(buffer(p1), buffer(p2));