# Geopandas spatial join - all points within an x meter radius

Tags: spatial, geopandas

I have a collection of Points (lat, long for a collection of buildings) and I want to group them based on whether they are within x meters of each other.  I know that I could do this pairwise by first using Geopandas buffer() function (with x/2 meter radius) and then using sjoin().  However, I don't want to just do this pairwise.  I want to group all buildings whose buffer region (the lat, long as the center and the buffer being a circle of radius x/2 meters) overlaps with ANY OTHER buffer region.

For example, if I have three buildings (denoted A, B and C), with each building 25 meters from its neighbor and I use a 25 meter buffer, then A and B can be grouped with sjoin() and B and C can be grouped, but I would want all THREE to be grouped.

That's in contrast to the case where A and B are 25 meters apart and C is 50 meters from B.  In that case, I would want to be able to group A and B together and C in its own group.

In reality, I have potentially 100 or more buildings, so it isn't possible to run all permutations pairwise.  I would need a function that groups multiple buildings whenever the building's buffer circle intersects with any other buffer circle.

Is there a simple way to do this with Geopandas?

Comment: i would expect the `overlay` functionality to cover this

Comment: I'd `buffer` all, `dissolve` by a constant value and `explode`. That will generate your clusters. Then you do `sjoin` to initial buildings to assign clusters to them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses.  I wound up doing the following:

- buffered each building's lat/long Point by a set distance, in meters (** see note below **)
- determined the geopandas.unary_union of all of the buffers to get a multi-polygon (list of polygons)
- wrote a custom function to identify which polygon in the list intersects with a specific buildings Point (using geopandas's .intersection), and called that list index the "location group"
- used panda's apply with the above function to get the "location group" that each building belonged to
- used panda's groupby to sum the values based on the "location group"

For the above, I had to be a bit careful about edge cases where the intersection was not a multipolygon but rather a polygon (or even a Point, in cases where the buffer was zero).

A bigger issue I ran into was enormous trouble getting geopanda's buffer function to work properly.  I know that this has to do with the crs/projections and tried all sorts of variations, but could never get the buffer function to work properly with the buffer distance in meters.  I found a nice custom function here ([Is there an easy way to create square buffers around point and if they intersect, merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083290/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-square-buffers-around-point-and-if-they-intersect)) that did work, but then realized that my Postgres setup has the PostGIS functions and used ST_Buffer to get the buffer polygons at the same time I am querying the database for the building lat/long data.

Hopefully the above will be helpful to others.